# How to modify Drupal site on OpenShift using SFTP?

Tags: drupal, openshift, drupal-theming

I have Drupal 7 set up on my OpenShift account using the Drupal 7 quick start. I have set up WinSCP to navigate the directory, and I can get to app-root/data/sites/all/, which is where custom Drupal mods go. I've installed the Zen theme as well.

However, when I try to change any of the template files in app-root/data/sites/all/themes/zen/templates, none of the changes show up at my site's publicly accessible URL. I've tried clearing the Drupal cache and the browser cache, but still it doesn't work.

At other hosts, I've never had this issue with Drupal. This problem seems specific to OpenShift. Any idea what's going on? Am I working in the wrong directory? Do I not have access to the live files?

Comment: After you make your changes to your data directory try restarting your app.

Comment: Restarting my php5 cart did make Drupal use the modified template file. However, the next time I modified a template, the change did not go through. It appears that I need to restart the php5 cart each time I update a template.