# Why is my OpenShift repo not copied to new gears during scaling?

Tags: php, openshift, scaling

I can see my app's code in the OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR, but not in the "/app-deployments" directory. I think each cartridge (on the different gears) should have its own copy of runtime data. (I've modified the scaling settings via the web console, from 1-3 to 3-3. Now my app shows the OpenShift default index page, instead of the expected content.)

Comment: Are you using git push to deploy your code? Or are you using something like SCP to copy your code to your gear?

Comment: Last time I used SFTP (FileZilla), because [it seemed to be supported](https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/) by OpenShift.

Comment: I've found [a similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223127/how-to-modify-drupal-site-on-openshift-using-sftp). Unfortunatelly, restarting doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling will only work correctly if you are using git to upload your files.  When you use "git add" and "git push" to deploy your website to openshift, it creates a 'deployments' folder which is copied to the other gears using rsync when your appliation is scaled up.  Just using SFTP to copy your files to the ~/app-root/repo directory will not work with a scaled application.

Comment: Good to know... I wonder why isn't it mentioned in any of the official OpenShift pages, that scaling is a git-only service.